# How can I display a form button on top of the form?

Tags: 7, forms

In my custom module, I have added a button to the node edit form, using the following code.

```
  $form['actions']['my_submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('My custom action'),
    '#weight' => -1000,
    '#submit' => array('node_form_submit', 'my_custom_node_form_submit')
  );
```

It is currently displayed either to the left or to the right of the standard "Save" button, depending on the weight value. Is there a way to display it on top of the form, before the first field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `$form['actions']['my_submit']` like this, then you will get the button inside `$form['actions']`. `$form['actions']` weight would be considered with the weight of other fields. Try the following code.

```
 $form['my_submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('My custom action'),
  '#weight' => -1000,
  '#submit' => array('node_form_submit', 'my_custom_node_form_submit')
 );
```