# How to place all form buttons on top of the page, before the form, in all forms?

Tags: forms

Since these forms can get quite big sometimes, especially with a lot of files attached and default preview for them.

Related, but not the same: [How can I display a form button on top of the form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/70503/7177)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using `hook_form_alter()` and setting the weight of `$form['actions']` to a very small negative number.  Note that this applies only those buttons wrapped in `$form['actions']`. For other buttons that they aren't, you should add them manually.

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['actions']['#weight'] = -1000;
  // a button that is not wrapped in actions.
  // assuming it's id is 'submit'
  $form['submit']['#weight'] = -1000;
}
```

Comment: It's the answer for and from the related question I've mentioned. I'm not asking about my module, the question is about affecting all forms.

Comment: This answer IS for all forms. You should place this code in your module.

Comment: Guess I was distracted and didn't pay enough attention at the time.

Answer (score 1):

The module for that is part of the [Util](https://drupal.org/project/util) package and is called, unsurpsingly, Top Buttons.

### Drush:

```
drush dl util
drush en -y top_buttons
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer above, #weight needs to be accessed with a preceding #. Also, you should check if the form elements exist before modifying them to avoid getting warnings in your logs.

Something like the below might work:

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($form['actions'])) {
    $form['actions']['#weight'] = -1000;
  }
  if (isset($form['submit'])) {
    $form['submit']['#weight'] = -1000;
  }
}
```

Also, this solution assumes you have a custom module for your site. If you don't, you'll need to research how to set one up first.

Comment: This code would go in your own module, but would effect forms from any module. hook_form_alter() runs on every form.